# How do browsers discover username and password on all web pages?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

How do browsers discover username and password on all web pages?

What is script that is used for determine username textbox and password for saving them?

Like search for element with type="password"?

Comment: As far as I know, this is just assumption made by browsers based on `<input name="username">` where name can be well known names like `user`, `username`, `email` etc. If you put in your web application `<input name="abracadabra">` it won't distinguish it from any other form and thus won't treat it as username/password form. Other assumptions could be taken into account like `type` of input etc. You may test it your self with simple web application form (i'm not sure that it will be testable with static local html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fire fox use from this script:
[enter link description here](http://%20https://dxr.mozilla.org/firefox/source/toolkit/components/passwordmgr/src/nsLoginManager.js)